# Module 'ngRoute' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-routing

I have linked the script in my index.html, and referenced it in app.js, but I keep getting the error that ngRoute is not available.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

app.js

```
angular.module('gameMaster', ['ngRoute', 'castServices']);
```

.config

```
angular.module('gameMaster')    
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
        //welcome page
        .when('/welcome', {
            templateUrl: '../../../../pages/welcome.html',
            controller: 'gameController'
        })

        //gameplay page
        .when('/gameplay',{
            templateUrl: '../../../../pages/gameplay.html',
            controller: 'gameController'
        })

        //default to welcome
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/welcome'
        });
    $locationProvider.html5mode(true);
});
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Party Things!</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modules/castServices/castServices.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modules/gameMaster/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

Does anything jump out at you?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any other errors on the page (e.g. one of the files doesn't load properly)?

Comment: It seems OK. Could you try to reproduce it on live environment / JSFiddle and give us a link?

Comment: As per the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28761037/2451726), can you replace script type is `javascript` and not `text/javascript`

Comment: I changed text/javascript to just javascript with no difference.  As far as the errors I get, this is all that pops on the page:

`Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module gameMaster due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

Comment: There are lots of other files that load in for the app, or I'd stick it up on fiddle or something -- I edited my answer to include the .config... If I drop the .config and the 'ngRoute' dependency, everything works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had caching issues.  I went into the developer options and disabled cache while the pane was open, and viola.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 22):

Just for the record. Now Angular distributes ngRoute module as a separate file - 
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

You need to download angular-route.js and include in your webpage:

```
<script src="angular.js">
<script src="angular-route.js">
```

Comment: I got the question error while bootstrapping AngularJS inside Angular. So this answer gave me the tip to solve my problem with `$ npm install angular-route`.